# Lambda function almacenar en DynamoDB

Tags: nodejs, aws, lambda, dynamodb

Estoy intentando crear una función en Lambda que haga una request a Google Page Speed API y me almacene la respuesta en Dynamo DB.
El la respuesta de la API la recibo correctamente y el Item en la base de datos lo esta creando pero no estoy logrando integrar el cuerpo de la respuesta en el Item.
Que estoy haciendo mal ?

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({region: 'us-east-1'});

var https = require('https');
    exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    let gpsdata = "";
    
    let params = {
        Item: {
        date: Date.now(),
        message: gpsdata,
        },
        TableName: 'gpsdata', 
    };
    var API_KEY= "MY_API_KEY";
    let rawData = "";
    var params2 = {
                host: "pagespeedonline.googleapis.com",
                path: `/pagespeedonline/v5/runPagespeed?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.unapagina.com%2F&key=${API_KEY}`
                };
    var req = https.request(params2, function(res) {
    console.log('STATUS: ' + res.statusCode);
    res.setEncoding('utf8');
    res.on('data', function(chunk) {
        rawData += chunk;
        gpsdata = JSON.stringify(rawData);
    });
    res.on('end', async function() {
        // console.log(rawData);
         
         console.log(params.Item.message);
        try {
           docClient.put(params, function(err, gpsdata){
                if(err){
                    callback(err, null);
                }else{
                  callback(null, gpsdata);
                }
            });
            } catch (e) {
      console.error(e.message);
    }
    });
  });
  req.end();
 };
```

Answer (score 0):

Falta actualizar el campo: params.Item.message ya que luego de recibir la respuesta este campo no está siendo actualizado